# Random number of dice with random number of faces-Probability of getting a max number provided

Tags: probability, dice

Suppose we have a vector $y$ that represent $m$ dice with a potentially varying number of faces (let's call this number $k_i$, where $i$ goes from $1$ to $m$). Let's also suppose that $x_{max}$ is an input that states the max number that can be present in any combination of the dice after being thrown, and that must be present in *at least one* of these.

I'm interested in the probability of such an event, so I would need a generic formula where I can provide a vector $y$ of $m$ dices with $k_i$ faces and max integer $x_{max}$.

I understand that the probability of at least one case occurring would be:

$$
P(X) = \prod_{i=1}^{m} \frac{1}{k_i}
$$

To consider all cases that fit the criterion I would need to multiply $P(X)$ by the number of all cases $n$, that would yield $P(T)$. This is where I'm having a problem: Im not sure how to arrive at the generic formula to calculate all the possible cases that fit the criterion.

I have arrived at a solution where I generate all permutations and discard the ones that fit the criteria, via programming, but it's not the most efficient method.

Here's a couple of examples:

$$
1) y = [2,5,8],
x_{max} = 8,
P(T) = 0.125
$$
$$
2) y=[2, 5, 7, 3],
x_{max} = 3,
P(T) = 0.180952380952
$$
$$
3)y = [3,4]
x_{max} = 2
P(T) = 0.25
$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll write $x =x_{max}$. I'm assuming a dice with $k_i$ faces shows integers between $1$ and $k_i$.

We can consider this the probability that no die shows higher than $x$ (I.e. all dice show $\leq x$) minus the probability that all dice show $<x$. This comes out to (taking into account that probability cannot exceed $1$)

$$
{\prod_{i=1}^m \min\left\{\frac{x}{k_i},1\right\}} - {\prod_{i=1}^m \min\left\{\frac{x-1}{k_i},1\right\}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to reproduce your example (2)

So the dice have sides $2,5,7,3$, and  there are $2\times 5 \times 7 \times 3 = 210$ equally possible outcomes

We now want to count the ones where the maximum value is exactly $3$. Count the number of ways all the dice show less than or equal to $3$ and subtract the number of ways all the dice show less than or equal to $2$.  So $2 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 - 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 = 54-16=38$

This gives a probability as $\frac{38}{210} \approx  0.18095$, as you found

In general this becomes $$\dfrac{\prod_i \min\left\{x_{\max},k_i\right\}   - \prod_i \min\left\{x_{\max}-1,k_i\right\}}{\prod_i k_i}$$

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the first term of the numerator, wouldn't I have to use the term  *min* rather than *max*? Given that when it hits the first die of 2 faces, by using the *max* function it would come up 3, rather than 2?

Comment: @FrankPinto - yes indeed, they should both be $\min$ rather than $\max$